Geometry 15mm margin for Marie curie proposal
I would like to have a 15mm white margin for my latex for a a Marie Curie proposal for which the requirement is as follows:

The page size is A4, and all margins (top, bottom, left, right) should
be at least 15 mm (not including any footers or headers).

Hence I need 15mm magrin of white space and after these 15mm I would like to have a one line header and at the top and one line footer at the bottom (the page count).
I have tried this but for some reason the lower margin seems to eat a lot of space, a resource of which I have little I think more than 15mm. I am using fancy HDR and here is a MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=15mm,bottom=15mm,left=15mm,right=15mm,includeheadfoot,nofoot,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
%\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize LHS}
\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize RHS}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small Page \thepage~of \pageref*{sec:textend} }
\setlength{\headheight}{11pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum\footnote{Hello}
\lipsum

\label{sec:textend}
\end{document}

How can I ensure I have 15mm of white space then a one line header/footer?
Attached an image to show what I mean.

How can I adjust this to make better use of space?

Off-topic: top=15mm,bottom=15mm,left=15mm,right=15mm may be expressed more succinctly as margin=15mm.

Geometry adjusts the bottom margin by changing \textheight, so if you change other values (like \headheight) later, the calculations will be off.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=15mm,bottom=15mm,left=15mm,right=15mm,
  headheight=11pt,headsep=0pt,
  includeheadfoot,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
%\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize LHS}
\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize RHS}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small Page \thepage~of \pageref*{sec:textend} }

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum\footnote{Hello}
\lipsum

\label{sec:textend}
\end{document}


Thank you very much for this; one last point [I'm quite novice] would be how to reduce the space, between the text in the foot and the body of text? It is pretty conspicuous at the moment.

Ok I think I've figured it out from your answer I basically set footskip to 15pt as follows: \usepackage[top=15mm,bottom=15mm,left=15mm,right=15mm, footskip=15pt,headheight=11pt,head    sep=0pt,includeheadfoot,showframe]{geometry}
This foces geomtry to recompute textheight as a function of this constraint. Correct?

@Jpk - Rather than have headheight=11pt, you may prefer headheight=1\baselineskip.

@Jpk - Das ist eine grosse zehn vier, gute  kamerad!  (correct)
